# How to load php file through jQuery without advertising your technology

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Nowadays, Developers and Professionals tend to use PHP templates because of two reasons. They are manageable and secondly, we don't need to advertise our technology as there are no question marks and .php extensions within the URL.

But how to make non-advertisement of your technology possible while sending a jQuery Ajax request to load a PHP file in a `div`. I mean we would, have to write `$.get('phpfile.php')` within the script and one can say that voa he is using PHP hmmmm.

Simply, I want to ask is there is any way of loading a PHP through request without advertising your technology as above told.

Some coding will be honored.

Comment: If you use Apache as your server, have a look at [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: It is not a problem at all to write that in your Javascript.

Comment: So someone knows that web-scripting language you use - so what?

Comment: Well, the right thing is we don't need to hide our technology. I actually read Kevin Yank's 'Database driven websites using php and mySQL' and he focuses a lot in hiding your technology and even wrote 2 pages on that topic under "Hiding The Seems" heading at page 104.

Comment: @nav_nav if someone know what version of php/apache/whatever you use, he can use that info to attack your site against knows security problems about **that** specific technology.

Comment: @pomeh and how will they know the PHP version in use, from only seeing the `.php` extension at the end of URL's....

Comment: read my answer below. It's not only about files extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how to make non-advertisement of your technology possible while sending a jQuery ajax request to load a php file in a div. I mean we would, have to write $.load('phpfile.php') within the script and one can say that voa he is using PHP hmmmm.

I don't get it. jQuery doesn't know about PHP files. If your website has 2 "public pages" `www.example.com` and `www.example.com/foo`, then you can access to the `/foo` page from the homepage with something like `$.get("/foo")`. Here I use AJAX, jQuery, and nobody knows if my page use PHP or whatever.

Then, you should look for `mod_rewrite` has explained by verisimilitude, but rewriting url is not the unique solution. Have a look to this site http://builtwith.com/ and enter a random url. Web servers send, by default, a lot of data about themselves, so you should avoid that behavior too if you want to "hide" the technology used. Have a look here http://xianshield.org/guides/apache2.0guide.html. It's "a guide to installing and hardening an Apache 2.0 web server to common security standards.". You may find useful information in there.

**Edit**

And also, "PHP templates" are not related to pages URL at all. For example, you could have multiple URL which use the same "PHP template".

Comment: Well, the right thing is we don't need to hide our technology. I actually read Kevin Yank's 'Database driven websites using php and mySQL' and he focuses a lot in hiding your technology and even wrote 2 pages on that topic under "Hiding The Seems" heading at page 104.

Comment: I don't get your point. You says "we don't need to hide" then "I've read a book that tell we need to hide". Whaaat ?

Comment: @yusufiqbalpk I've updated my answer and added a link to http://xianshield.org/guides/apache2.0guide.html. You should have a look

Answer (score 1):

mod_rewrite is the best answer for all your predicaments. Why not use it? The URL phpfile.php in your above code could be rewritten to achieve the obfuscation...

Comment: can you give me some examples with mod_rewrite

Comment: Well, the right thing is we don't need to hide our technology. I actually read Kevin Yank's 'Database driven websites using php and mySQL' and he focuses a lot in hiding your technology and even wrote 2 pages on that topic under "Hiding The Seems" heading at page 104.

Answer (score 0):

@pomeh. Good point.

See. two things can be done here.

1) Disable the APACHE signature. In the default configuration of Apache, any page served through it will contain a full signature of the server. Server signatures contain valuable information about installed software and can be read (and exploited). Therefore is it safer to turn off this behavior. This is how you do it. Open Apache’s configuration file (httpd.conf or apache2.conf) and search for *ServerSignature* . Set it to 'Off'. After that search for *ServerTokens* and set it to 'Prod'.

2) Set "expose_php" in php.ini to false: Exposes to the world that PHP is installed on the server, which includes the PHP version within the HTTP header.

3) There are some php obfuscators available which also may be used. I will not recommend them since I've not personally tried them.

There are ways and means beyond these to hide the "technology". By default, a php enabled APACHE web server processes and interprets all files with .php extension. But we can bind any weirdo extension to hide the technology to be processed by the server..

Comment: I recommend to use .htaccess to do all the server config level things. It is not possible to completely stop the server from advertising itself but it can be reduced to a minimum.

Comment: Well, the right thing is we don't need to hide our technology. I actually read Kevin Yank's 'Database driven websites using php and mySQL' and he focuses a lot in hiding your technology and even wrote 2 pages on that topic under "Hiding The Seems" heading at page 104.

Comment: @verisimilitude you may like this ressource http://xianshield.org/guides/apache2.0guide.html

Comment: @yusufiqbalpk you may please refer to the link mentioned above by pomeh. But why this self-contradictory comment you've given above? do you really want to mask off your technology? If not then what is it that you are planning to do ? Please be specific when you post your comment or ask a question here so that we may guide you likewise.

Comment: From now on I'll be more specific. Thanks for your guidance

Answer (score 0):

I guess verisimilitude and pomeh already answered this question.

All web servers send information about themselves over the internet. You cant hide that.

If you want to hide file extensions, like 'aspx, php, asp, html' then you will need to use mod_rewrite under Apache or something like URL Rewrite under IIS7.

You can also set default documents under IIS7.  This really only works once per web folder. For example you can set default.htm as one of the default documents. When a visitor goes to your website they type www.domain.com and they get a web page. That visitor is actually looking at www.domain.com/default.htm

Comment: Well, the right thing is we don't need to hide our technology. I actually read Kevin Yank's 'Database driven websites using php and mySQL' and he focuses a lot in hiding your technology and even wrote 2 pages on that topic under "Hiding The Seems" heading at page 104.

Comment: actually, we **can** hide that information. Can you tell me which server side technology is used on stackoverflow ? http://builtwith.com/stackoverflow.com can't

Comment: If you don't mind can you write briefly all the points we need to hide that information here or some where else.

Comment: @user1252552 you may like this ressource http://xianshield.org/guides/apache2.0guide.html

Comment: I stand corrected gentleman. You can mask the details of your web server.